# How to convert avro data type using an external schema file in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I have two avro files having slightly different (write) schemas. The first one has column_a of type int, the second one has column_a of type long.

I am using an external avro schema file in a hive external table to query the data.
If i set the type of column_a to long i can select the data.

But is it somehow possible to set the data type to string in the external schema file, so that hive (or avro) automatically does the conversion to string?